# How do I dynamically change the height of a TableViewRow?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

- Application Type: mobile
- Titanium SDK: 3.1.0.GA
- Platform & version: iOS 6.1
- Device: iOS Simulator
- Host Operating System: OSX 10.8.3
- Titanium Studio: 3.1.0.201304151600

I'd like to conditionally show/hide a textfield in a TableViewRow. In order to do this I need to expand the height of the row. The following code doesn't work, though. The TableViewRow is actually an Alloy controller. I first tried animating it before I realized that it can't be animated. Now I'm just trying to change the height and that isn't even working. I've tried using the setHeight method along with just setting the height property directly to no avail.
Any ideas?

```
var notesVisible = false;

function notes_click() {

    if(notesVisible == false) {
        Ti.API.info('expanding');
        $.row.height = 200;
        // $.notes_container.setHeight(124);
        notesVisible = true;
    } else {
        Ti.API.info('contracting');
        $.row.height = 75;
        $.notes_container.setHeight(0);
        notesVisible = false;
    }

};
```

Comment: UPDATE: Not ideal, but the best "solution" I've found is to delete and re-add the row to the TableView control. It's definitely dirty, but it will work for the time being until a better answer surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two good ways of doing this, both should be done from the click event listener.

Method 1) One way is to directly change the "height" variable of the row
Method 2) The second is to create a new row and replace the current row with the new row

Method 1 is more straightforward but I found it to be glitchy depending on what version of the SDK you are using, but with 3.1.0 it should work.  Both methods should be called from the 'click' eventListener as its easier to tell Titanium which row to act on based on the click

So here is an example

```
currentTableview.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
  // DO whatever your row is supposed to do when clicked

  // Now lets change the height of the row to a new height, 200 in this example
  e.row.height = 200
}
```

With Method two, it involves creating a new row and then replacing the current row with this call

```
currentTableview.updateRow(e.index,newlyCreatedUpdatedRow);
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't see the updateRow method. I was calling deleteRow and insertRowBefore. updateRow is much cleaner, so thanks for that suggestion! I tried changing the height in the tableView's click event to no avail. It would never change the height. No exception either.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question asked by some one but the solution provided will not work and i think best solution for this is by making a recursive function and changes the height of your row and need to play with the visibility of views inside that row hopefully will help someone :)